# Using Java how to get the list of members from a google group

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-groups

I am new to google cloud. I am currently working on **Bigquery**.  For a project in bigquery, I am creating Authorized views through **java** using service account which is created in Bigquery. In this process I am in a situation where I have to create Authorized view for members of google group. For this I have thought about fetching the member of a google group and restricting / granting views accordingly.  Well I searched [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java#prerequisites) the google documentation, but I couldn't understand the credentials.json part.

1. For Bigquery in order to access from the java, we are creating a service account identified by a json file, so does this means I have to have two json file in my java code (one for bigquery and one for google groups) ?
2. And can any one share a link or any resource of a java code that fetches list of member of a gmail group.
3. Finally in order access the google apps like drive, gmail, etc through java do we need separate json file for each?

Thank you.